# CakePHP Containable Behavior Not Working As Expected

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I have the following database tables:

```
products
********
id
title
artist_id

artists
*******
id
profile
rating
person_id

people
******
id
full_name
```

With the following model associations:

```
Product Model
*************
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Artist' => array(
        'className'  => 'Artist'
        'foreignKey' => 'artist_id'
    )
);

Artist Model
************
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Person' => array(
        'className'  => 'Person'
        'foreignKey' => 'person_id'
    )
);
public $hasMany = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className'  => 'Product'
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
    )
);

Person Model
************
public $hasOne = array(
    'Artist' => array(
        'className'  => 'Artist'
        'foreignKey' => 'person_id'
    )
);
```

I have set each of the three models to use the Containable behaviour using:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

When I use the following to get the product details along with the artist's name:

```
$this->Product->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Product.id' => $id), 'contain' => 'Person.full_name'))
```

I get the warning:

```
Model "Product" is not associated with model "Person"
```

And I only get the product details ie no artist's name. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are calling the `find` operation on the `Product` model, and `Person` is not *directly* related to `Product`, but indirectly, by its relation to `Artist`. In this case, your `contain` array should be something like the following:

```
$this->Product->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Product.id' => $id), 
    'contain' => array('Artist' => 'Person.full_name')
));
```

This will return a result like

```
array(
    [Product] => array(...),
    [Artist] => array(
        [Person] => array(
             'full_name' => '...'
        )
    )
)
```